Why does "bc" read my config file on one computer and not another?
I have two old machines, running CentOS 6.5 and CentOS 6.10.
Both have bc 1.06.95-1.el6 installed.
One reads $HOME/.bc.rc, one does not. Why ? (How??)
strace shows near-identical output, except one reads the config file. The libraries are identical.

Turns out I had defined the BC_ENV_ARGS environment variable (GNU specific) to $HOME/.bc.rc in ~/.bashrc on one machine but not the other.
strace doesn't trace environment variable retrieval as that doesn't involve a system call (and -v is needed for the execve() system call trace to include the environment).
I have scale=3 set in .bc.rc, so I get 3 places of decimal by default.
